# How to project a polygon from openlayers referring latitude and longitude from kml file?

Tags: angular, openlayers

I need to display a point or polygon or linestring in my openlayer maps .I could display the point , not linestring and polygon. since im a beginner i dont know to work these.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the correct CRS (cordinate reference system) as projection to the source object in which you have linked your kml file.

Openlayers default projection is EPSG:4326, but the lat long projection is EPSG:3857.